# My webpage is not saving a field properly on SQL Server Management Studio, using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I made a webpage using ASP.NET with a survey where the values are saved in SQL Server management Studio, but I’m having problems with one field that is not saving the way that I want it to.
For example when I choose “Enero-Junio” it should save a 1 and when I choose “Agosto-Diciembre” a 2 (P1a), but also should save the las 2 numbers of the year (P1b).
For example if I choose “Enero-Junio” year 2014, the field saved in SqL Server should be “114”.
Always saves only the number "2"
Here’s the code from the .aspx file

```
<td class="style6"><strong>1. Periodo de egreso:</strong></td>
        <td class="style23"><asp:DropDownList ID="P1a" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Enero-Junio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Agosto-Diciembre</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="P1b" runat="server"
            MaxLength="4" Width="55px"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here’s the code behind .aspx.cs

```
if (Int32.Parse(dsDatosgenerales2.Comprometidas2[0]["Periodo"].ToString()) > 199)
                    {
                        int perido = Int32.Parse(dsDatosgenerales2.Comprometidas2[0]["Periodo"].ToString()) - 100;
                        P1a.SelectedValue = "Enero-Junio";
                        P1b.Text = "" + perido + "";  

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int perido = Int32.Parse(dsDatosgenerales2.Comprometidas2[0]["Periodo"].ToString()) - 200;
                        P1a.SelectedValue = "Agosto-Diciembre";
                        P1b.Text = "" + perido + "";

                    }
```

Comment: Bad design in my opinion. If you want to store the month and the year as numbers, store them in separate fields. OR create a table with every month and make the row's primary key match the pattern you want (i.e. there would be a row with a PK 114 and a description field that would read "January 2014").

Answer (score 0):

If you add Values to your list items, you will be able to pull the exact value that is selected.

for eg:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Enero-Junio</asp:ListItem>
```

You can then get the value using

```
int person = int.Parse(P1a.SelectedValue); // Will = 1 or 2 based on your selction
```

You can then append the year to the end of this value. See the below snippet.

`int person = int.Parse(P1a.SelectedValue);
int year = int.Parse(P1b.Text);
string answer = string.Format("{0}{1:yy}",person,new DateTime(year,1,1));`

You would just need to validate that the value entered into Plb is a valid year

Comment: That said - I do agree with Ghosts comment above as if you have more than 9 items in your drop down list it will become difficult to know where to start extracting the data

Comment: Sasha, how could I append the year to that value?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited my answer, showing you how to append it

Comment: Thanks
So I delete this "if":
if (Int32.Parse(dsDatosgenerales2.Comprometidas2[0]["Periodo"].ToString()) > 199)
And which the new "if" should be?

Comment: Yes - It's not needed at all to append the two values together? I'm not sure why you need an "if" statement?